# React Native Picker "com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: label"

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile, native

My app crashes on launch, after installing "@react-native-community/picker" and auto linking.

I get the following errors:

```
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: label
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getNullableValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:123)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getNullableValue(ReadableNativeMap.java:127)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getString(ReadableNativeMap.java:162)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativecommunity.picker.ReactPickerManager$ReactPickerAdapter.getView(ReactPickerManager.java:146)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativecommunity.picker.ReactPickerManager$ReactPickerAdapter.getView(ReactPickerManager.java:127)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:204)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:602)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:428)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23355)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativecommunity.picker.ReactPicker$2.run(ReactPicker.java:76)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
08-12 18:40:27.528 25856 25856 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.linkmood.app, PID: 26173
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.IconResolver$1.onError(IconResolver.java:35)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader.loadIcon(ImageLoader.kt:46)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.IconResolver.resolve(IconResolver.java:27)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.ButtonPresenter.loadIcon(ButtonPresenter.kt:121)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.ButtonPresenter.applyIcon(ButtonPresenter.kt:74)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.ButtonPresenter.applyOptions(ButtonPresenter.kt:43)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.button.ButtonController.addToMenu(ButtonController.kt:82)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.TopBarController.lambda$applyRightButtons$1$TopBarController(TopBarController.java:122)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.-$$Lambda$TopBarController$rlIV_MYFMKIvSNp70rm34RXTfHA.run(Unknown Source:8)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.CollectionUtils.forEachIndexed(CollectionUtils.java:130)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.topbar.TopBarController.applyRightButtons(TopBarController.java:122)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.StackPresenter.applyButtons(StackPresenter.java:280)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.StackPresenter.applyChildOptions(StackPresenter.java:140)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.stack.StackController.onAttachToParent(StackController.java:95)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.viewcontrollers.viewcontroller.ViewController.onGlobalLayout(ViewController.java:287)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:945)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2544)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1637)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7797)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1172)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:984)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:809)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1158)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1073)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader$Companion.remoteUrl(ImageLoader.kt:124)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader$Companion.openStream(ImageLoader.kt:119)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader$Companion.access$openStream(ImageLoader.kt:111)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader.readJsDevImage(ImageLoader.kt:81)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader.getDrawable(ImageLoader.kt:71)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.reactnativenavigation.utils.ImageLoader.loadIcon(ImageLoader.kt:44)
08-12 18:40:46.297 26173 26173 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 28 more
```

Been debugging this for a few hours now, but can't for the life of me figure it out. I've tried commenting out every single picker in the project as well, but this still happens.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be good if you can add the piece of code generating the error so it's easier to help you